# Como ocultar dados de acesso à API javascript?

Tags: jquery, web-service, token

Como faço para ocultar essas informações que passo como parâmetro para a requisição do token? do jeito que ta qualquer um pode ver e não pode

```
var chaveToken = {
                "grant_type": "password",
                "username": "xxxxxxxxx@example.com",
                "password": "xxxxxxxxxx@121111"
            };       
    var token;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http:/xxxxxx.com.br/token',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                type: 'POST',
                data: chaveToken,
                success: function (data) {
                    token = data.access_token);                        
                }
            });            


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://xxxxxx.com.br/obterlistasreembolso',
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + Token);
            },
            success: function (data) {
               bla bla bla
            }                
        });
```

Comment: Se não pode expor os dados, não utilize essa API por JavaScript. Faça a requisição com uma linguagem server-side.

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha sido claro no comentário anterior: em JS não vai ter como esconder esses dados.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @bfavaretto comentou, não há como esconder essas credenciais utilizando a `API` em javascript. Para isso, utilize a versão server-side dela.

Answer (score 0):

Como isso é client-side não dá para esconder.
O que você tem que fazer é obter o token através do servidor (server-side) utilizando alguma linguagem como PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, Java/JSP, Javascript (se for pelo Node.js) e então você passa pra página apenas o token já obtido.

Se nem o token puder ser visto pelo usuário, então você deverá modificar sua aplicação para funcionar como um proxy para a API, onde o usuário chama "ações" na sua aplicação e então ela consome a API do serviço que você está usando ai no JS.

Só se atente ao fato de que o token podem ser gerado baseado no IP da requisição, sendo assim, se você gerar o token pelo server-side, o token vai ser gerado para o IP do seu servidor e se você optar pela primeira alternativa de passar somente o token para a página, quando o o usuário fizer a requisição com o token, a requisição será pela pelo IP dele (já que é client-side) e por isso a API pode informar que o token não é válido (isso você descobre pela documentação da API ou realizando testes mesmo), neste caso você será obrigado a fazer a segunda alternativa, transformando sua aplicação em um proxy para a API pelo server-side.